# ExtJS xtype menu times out in Chrome

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a an ExtJS app that uses xtype menu to create a dropdown menu with two options. One of those options, on mouseover, brings up two additional sub options. When attempting to mouseover one of the sub options, the menu immediately times out and disappears.

This only happens in Chrome. Safari is fine. Also if I use the keyboard arrows to make the selection it works fine.

```
Ext.define('App.view.deposit.ReportButton', {
extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
alias: 'widget.depositreporbutton',
requires: [
    'Ext.menu.Menu',
    'Ext.menu.Separator'
],
text: 'Reports',
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        menu: {
            xtype: 'menu',
            minWidth: 200,
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Deposit Report',
                    menu: {
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'menuitem',
                                itemId: 'deposit-report-media-button',
                                text: 'By Media Type'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'menuitem',
                                itemId: 'deposit-report-fund-button',
                                text: 'By Income Fund'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                    itemId: 'receipt-report-button',
                    text: 'Contribution Receipts'
                }
            ]
        }
    });
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Comment: If you are using ExtJs 4 in Chrome 43 then there is a bug. Check this https://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=134&a=58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using extjs 4.x there is an issue with the Chrome 43 updates and the 4.x series.

Here's the bug thread: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301116-Submenus-disappear-in-Chrome-43-beta

Here is an announcement with a fix here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?a=58

Here's the official fix:

```
Ext.define('Override.menu.Menu', {
    override: 'Ext.menu.Menu',

    compatibility : '4',

    onMouseLeave: function(e) {
        var me = this;

        // If the mouseleave was into the active submenu, do not dismiss
        if (me.activeChild) {
            if (e.within(me.activeChild.el, true)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        me.deactivateActiveItem();
        if (me.disabled) {
            return;
        }
        me.fireEvent('mouseleave', me, e);
    }
});
```

You can try it out here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ndn

To use the override in your application:

1. Put the override file in the `overrides` directory off the root folder
2. Add this to the `app.js` file:

   ```
   Ext.Loader.setConfig({
       paths: {
           'Overrides': 'overrides'
       }
   });
   ```
3. Add the requires statement in the `Application.js` file under the `Ext.Define` section:

   ```
   Ext.define('Your.Application', {
       name: 'App',
       extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
       ...
       requires: [
           'overrides.Menu'
       ]
   });
   ```

Comment: Here is an official solution provided by Sencha - https://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=134&a=58

Comment: Thanks, missed the announcement. I've updated to use the official fix

Comment: I'm still a newb at ExtJS and have no idea where to put overrides. I created a file called MenuOverride.js with the code above and am now trying get it to be recognized. I do not have a generated "overrides" folder as some articles have suggested. I use Sencha Cmd to build. And yes I'm on 4.x.

Comment: @FiremanRob You will need to reference the file in the `app/Application.js` file.

In my case I created an overrides folder  as it wasn't auto-generated. In there I have a "Menu.js" file with the `Ext.define` statement having `overrides.Menu` instead of `Overrides.menu.Menu` (the Ext.define statement should match the directory structure). In my sencha.cfg I have the following line: `app.overrides=${app.dir}/overrides` and in my Application.js I reference the file in the 'views' section with: `overrides.Menu`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ZeroCool, thank you! This helps and it works now. The only thing that is confusing to me is how it is able to find it when referenced in the 'views' section. I would think it would expect to find an overrides folder with Menu.js in the view folder.

Comment: @FiremanRob I've changed my setup and wanted to let you know. I've edited my answer to include more information.